# Thymeleaf - How to loop a list by index

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, thymeleaf, each

How can I loop by index?

Foo.java

```
public Foo {
    private List<String> tasks;
    ...
}
```

index.html

```html
<p>Tasks:
    <span th:each="${index: #numbers.sequence(0, ${foo.tasks.length})}">
        <span th:text="${foo.tasks[index]}"></span>
    </span>
</p>
```

I got parse error

```
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as each: "${index: #numbers.sequence(0,  ${student.tasks.length})}"
```

Comment: Why do you need to use the index when you can already just iterate over the collection?

Comment: Eventually, I want to convert the list to comma delimeted string. I would like to check if the item is the last element. So I must loop by index first.

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Thymeleaf `th:each` allows you to declare an iteration status variable

```html
<span th:each="task,iter : ${foo.tasks}">
```

Then in the loop you can refer to `iter.index` and `iter.size`.

See [Tutorial: Using Thymeleaf - 6.2 Keeping iteration status](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status).

Answer (score 51):

Thymeleaf always declares implicit iteration status variable if we omit it.

```html
<span th:each="task : ${foo.tasks}">
    <span th:text="${taskStat.index} + ': ' + ${task.name}"></span>
</span>
```

Here, the status variable name is `taskStat` which is the aggregation of variable `task` and the suffix `Stat`.

Then in the loop, we can refer to `taskStat.index`, `taskStat.size`, `taskStat.count`, `taskStat.even` and `taskStat.odd`, `taskStat.first` and `taskStat.last`.

<sup>Source: [Tutorial: Using Thymeleaf - 6.2 Keeping iteration status](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please excuse my poor English.

Please be aware that, in my experience, the status variable ([1]), regarding `index` and `count` values, DOES not keep track of the status of the iteration, but returns the position of the current object in the list you're looping for.

For example.
You have a list called `pairs` of 6 pairs like this

```
    0: [id=10, fk=2]
    1: [id=20, fk=2]
    2: [id=30, fk=2]
    3: [id=40, fk=1]
    4: [id=50, fk=1]
    5: [id=60, fk=1]
```

and you want to print those who have `fk=1` BEFORE those who have `fk=2` (it's an example, sorting is not important, here).

So, if you use a `th_each="p:${pairs}"` followed by a `th:if="p.id == 1"`, you'll obtain

```
    [id=40, fk=1]
    [id=50, fk=1]
    [id=60, fk=1]
    (...)
```

as expected.
But, what are you expecting from `pStat.index` and `pStat.count` values?
I guess

```
    (0,1)
    (1,2)
    (2,3)
```

but (please verify using a `<pre>([[${pStat.index}]], [[${pStat.count}]])</pre>`), you'll obtain

```
    (3,4)
    (4,5)
    (5,6)
```

that is to say, the position of these pairs in the list, not the status of the iteraction itself.
This could be fine for you, but be aware that, for example, if you try to keep a count on how much times you looped extracting data from a list o hundred objects (for example to insert a `<br />` every ten values) results can surprise you, if the sequence of the list is not the sequence in which you'll use it.

If this is your case, a way to obtain this is extracting sublist using Collection Selection ([2]) in conjunction with Thymeleaf's `#lists.toList()` as in
`<th:block th:with="sublist=${#pairs.toList(list.?[fk ==1])}">`.

This way you'll obtain

```
    0: [id=40, fk=1]
    1: [id=50, fk=1]
    2: [id=60, fk=1]
```

and your first pair will have index `0` and count `1`.

Maybe this is a bug of the current verison of thymeleaf I'm using, or is not so clearly stated in documentation, but this is what I discovered staring at few code lines unexpectedly behaving (and some debugging).

Thymeleaf Iterations [1]: https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status

SpEL Collection Selection [2]: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/expressions/language-ref/collection-selection.html