# For Loop in Thyme-leaf with Maps MVC

Tags: html, spring-boot, for-loop, model-view-controller, thymeleaf

I found how to do for loop from 1 to 5, and also how to print a map, but couldn't find both together.

I have the following:

```
<tr th:each="mapEntry : ${users}">
  <td><a target="_blank" th:href="@{'https://github.com/' + ${mapEntry.key}}"><span th:text="${mapEntry.key}"></span></a></td>
  <td th:each="item : ${mapEntry.value}" th:text="${item}"></td>
</tr>
```

I am trying to print only first 10 values. How could I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thymeleaf - How to loop a list by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367339/thymeleaf-how-to-loop-a-list-by-index). Specifically, use the [iteration status](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status) features of Thymeleaf, and check the status using `th:if`.

Comment: Yes. However, it's a too short answer. He could give an example. Thanks.

Comment: OK - Understood - see if this helps: For the `th:each` tag, use something like this: `th:each="mapEntry,iterStat : ${users}"`. And then for the inner tags, you can choose to display only those where the counter has not reached the maximum count - something like this: `th:if="${iterStat.index} &lt; 10"`. You add this to the tag you want to conditionally display.

Comment: Thanks. I think I did th:if="${iterStat.index < 10}" and worked fine.