# Thymeleaf Iteration: Use index as ArrayIndex inside th:each loop

Tags: java, loops, thymeleaf

I want to use the index of an thymeleaf-loop as arrayindex inside.
Example:

```
<div th:each="service : ${requestedServices}">
   <div class="col-sm-1">
       <input type="checkbox" th:checked=*{service[index of loop?].requested}">
   </div>
</div>
```

I'll already tried to use serviceStat.index inside the array

${requestedServices} is an ArrayList of Requested Service

```
class RequestedService {
   Service service
   boolean requested
}
```

```
class Service {
   String name;
   int value;
}
```

I hope to find an answer for my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thymeleaf - How to loop a list by index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367339/thymeleaf-how-to-loop-a-list-by-index)

Answer (score 0):

`serviceStat.index`  is the correct way to to index into your array (see the last paragraph of [keeping iteration status](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#keeping-iteration-status) -- `If you don’t explicitly set a status variable, Thymeleaf will always create one for you by suffixing Stat to the name of the iteration variable:`).

That being said, because you are using it in a `th:field` attribute, you must use preprocessing for your index.

```
<div th:each="service : ${requestedServices}">
   <div class="col-sm-1">
       <input type="checkbox" th:checked="*{service[__${serviceStat.index}_].requested}" />
   </div>
</div>
```

(You might also be interested in the [Thymeleaf tutorial on dynamic fields](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields).)